# Angular 6 Material Dialog Font Discrepancies and Material Icon Size Modification

Tags: angular-material-6

I'm creating a sample app using material design as per what I've learned so far, but I noticed that the out of the box fonts for the material design are different for different components.  For the material title element within a material dialog, the title shows in a nice Roboto font but the material dialog content shows in Roman:
[image]

Here's my html component for the dialog:

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>{‌{title}}</h3>
<mat-icon color="primary">error_outline</mat-icon>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let error of errorMessages">
          {‌{error}}
        </li>    
      </ul>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

I don't want to have to create custom styles but would rather use the default styles associated with the element right out of the box.   If I add

```
body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

to my gobal styles.css that fixes the font within the mat-dialog-content but I'd rather not have to do that.

Also, the icon is so tiny as you can clearly see out of the box. Is there a way to choose a larger icon set from the icons library at runtime?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you have imported the fonts and font icons. Have you imported a predefined them in your application or are you theming it yourself? Fonts are applied by theming - if you aren't seeing the right font anywhere it's either because you haven't properly themed your application or because you have changed the font somewhere in style.

Comment: Hi G.Tranter, thanks for your response, yes I've applied one of the OOTB themes in my global styles.css :
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
and have imported the icons in my index.html:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

That's it, no other custom styling as that is what I wanted to avoid anyhow.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to add the `mat-typography` class to your app's `<body>` element.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue with Angular 7 Material.

Comment: Hi! any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the only way I can see from my research is by defining the body element within the global styles.css like so:

```
 body {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```